# Which metric for inter-annotator agreement of rated independent items?

Tags: statistical-significance, agreement-statistics, metric

I'm looking for a suitable metric that measures the agreement between many annotators `m` (say, 15) annotating a set of independent product reviews `n` (say, 20). I therefore have a matrix of shape `n x m = 20 x 15` containing integer ratings $r_{nm}$ ranging from 1 to 4.

**The reviews are not ranked among them**, each $r_{nm}$ correspond to a rating on a scale from 1 to 4 that measures the constructiveness of each review.

My goal is to measure to which extent the 15 annotators agree on the ranking of the 20 reviews while taking the notion of rank into account, i.e two annotators rating a review `1` and `4` disagree more than if they had rated it `1` and `2`.

Thank you guys for your input!

Comment: It might be a little bit late, but as I had the same problem I found this paper https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RankAggreg/vignettes/RankAggreg.pdf that present several suitable alternatives.

Comment: What method did you end up using OP?

Comment: I ended up making my own metric, here is the repo, but I cannot guarantee that it either still works or is adapted to other cases than mine https://github.com/ugolbck/kendall-w